# Is there a way to connect to DB2 on z/os using a jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, db2, ascii, translation, ebcdic

Am evaluating options **other than** either Sybase's DirectConnect or IBM's DB2Connect to connect to DB2 running on z/OS. From what our findings have shown us so far, we need to connect and also do format translation from ASCII to EBCDIC and vice versa. We are currently seeking an open source (not necessarily community edition) to help us achieve this. Any thoughts will always help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB2 Data Server Client allows you to connect to a DB2 database on z/OS using JDBC without requiring DB2 Connect in between. However, you will still need a DB2 Connect license, contained in the db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar file that comes with any DB2 Connect product.

Comment: Are there any other jdbc drivers which will allow connectivity to DB2 UDB on z/os from a non-z/OS system ? I am not looking for any driver which requires either a DirectConnect or DB2Connect license.

Comment: Also, whether we need to setup some kind of a "connect" style server which will proxy and bridge the requests/responses to/from DB2 on z/OS ? We need the ASCII <-> EBCDIC conversion capability OOTB in the solution. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The driver itself will handle the codepage conversion. However, I'm not aware of any other product offering the DB2 Connect functionality.