# DB2 EBCDIC To ASCII

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, db2, mainframe

I have a particular use case wherein we need data from DB2 running on z/OS into a relational database for further reporting/analytics use cases.

I've gone through the below post/link where it seems JDBC driver of DB2 can be used to read the data in readable format for RDBMS systems.

[DB2 JDBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725910/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-db2-on-z-os-using-a-jdbc-driver)

We do have other options too wherein we can export the DB2 tables data within Mainframe and FTP the files out, and then convert them using Manually coded options, like the ones below. However, these are not our preferred options over JDBC.

[Java program to convert EBCDIC to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368740/java-program-to-convert-ebcdic-to-ascii)

[Python program to convert EBCDIC to ASCII](https://thepythoncorner.com/posts/2020-04-30-working-with-ebcdic-python/)

This question is to further understand the implications of using a JDBC Driver to read data from DB2 running on z/OS and loading the data into an RDBMS.

For the sake of the discussion, we can assume that I am trying to load the data into a BigQuery dataset/table in GCP. We are not looking for custom built or open source solutions for this purpose.

For any queries, please let me know.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Db2 for Z/OS is RDBMS as well like whatever other RDBMS. The JDBC driver your mentioned should do string codepage conversions between server and client correctly like any other JDBC driver for whatever other RDBMS. So, it's not clear what exact problem you have with this. Could you describe your problem(s) in more detail?

Comment: One issue that bites the midrange IBM i (another EBCDIC platform) folks is that systems originally shipped with CCSID 65535 (aka binary) and when a character string in a table is tagged with CCSID 65535, then the DB thinks it's binary data and doesn't try to convert it.   The correct fix is to make sure your data is tagged with the correct CCSID.  But at with with the IBM i JDBC driver, there's a "force translate" option.

Comment: Operational matters, like reporting-time-lag, concurrency, referential-integrity, fitting into the schedule on the Z/OS subsystem, handling encrypted tables/column etc. are usually far more pressing matters than the interface (e.g jdbc) used for extraction.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBarinstein : I was simply looking for a confirmation based experience (which I don't have with mainframes and DB2 database) that the JDBC driver would naturally provide the codepage conversions. Once I get access to the DB2 running on z/OS then I'll try this and update this thread for everyone's benefit.